# HQl equivalent of sql query

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Url as U where U.pageType=" + 1 + " group  by U.pageId having count(U.pageId) = 1)";
query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
```

I am getting an error

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 23 [ SELECT count() FROM (SELECT * FROM Url as U where U.pageType = 2 group by U.pageId having count(U.pageId) = 1)]

Comment: To format source code there's the {} button in the editor ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and having and subqueries in hql as well.

Some examples:

[link text](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be ok as HQL code. Pay attention to the Capital letters for the entities: for example `url` in your bean class could be `Url`.

Anyway there's the method `createSQLQuery(queryString)` to run a query in SQL language.

Answer (score 0):

In HQL you cannot use subqueries in `FROM` clause.

In this particular case (with `having count(U.pageId) = 1`) the same result should be produced by the following query (though I'm not sure about performance):

```
SELECT count(u) FROM Url u WHERE u.pageType = 2 AND
    1 = (SELECT count(uu) FROM Url uu WHERE u.pageId = uu.pageId)
```

If it's not suitable, you can use `session.createSQLQuery()`.

Comment: The above query works but thats not what i need.. I need an exact equivalent to the below sql query in Hql: i understand i cant use subqueries in from clause but just wondering if there is a work around for the below..............                                                                                                                                                        select  count(*)  from  (select * from Url where page_type = 2  group by page_id having (count(page_id) =1))